# How can I add dot net dependency across all functions in Azure Function app

Tags: .net, azure, dependencies, azure-functions

I have three azure functions, I have created project.json and added the following for each function.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

How can I save the project.json in single place and use it in all Azure functions?

Note: I am also using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in Shared/CustomHelper.csx and calling this helper from Azure function.

Answer (score 3):

Global dependencies are not supported in the CSX/Scripting model.

If the only global dependency you need is Json.NET, you can bypass the package reference altogether and just reference it using the assembly simple name as:

```
    #r "Newtonsoft.Json"
```

Also, have a look at precompiled functions: there you have a C# project that references any NuGet packages and contains multiple functions, so functions share the packages. Defining helper classes is then also a matter of adding a class to the project.